# Code works in 'Tailwind Play' but doesn't work in VS Code when I paste it in

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

Tailwind newbie here.

I followed a video on YouTube on how to add an image slide on hover, but it didn't work when I tried it in VS Code. Later, I saw in the description a link to 'Tailwind Play' that had a copy of the code in the video. It works flawlessly in 'Tailwind Play'. I then copied the code on to VS Code, but it doesn't appear as intended in the browser.

In the video, he uses w-16 class at *1.11 min* into the video, but when I do the same, it does not change the width of the image.

Also, the gradient and words do not appear on hover in mine. But the the image does scale on hover for me.

Tailwind is installed properly afaik because it works properly in the other pages I made.

I'm using Google Chrome.

[The YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqDKsvL0jro&list=PLQPaZXNW9YUYNyZuiBRzVKg6XiXR6V7TL&index=8)

[Link to the Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MjN8woEKwR)

[Image of my file structure and head tag in VS Code; here, I pasted the code within the body tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo0Bb.png)

[Image of how it appears to me in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vehKN.jpg)

[Image of how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6GJf.png)

Each image scales, rotates, words appear and a gradient is applied on hover.

I tried removing class by class in the html but I couldn't figure out what the problem was.
I also tried unticking styles one by one in the chrome dev tools.
Here I found a style that specified the  tag to be width: 100% ; even though the class w-16 was applied in VS Code.

[width: 100%;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVpqD.jpg)

[w-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD5ua.png)

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong since morning. Any help or advice is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Edit: Figured out what was wrong. It seems like I've configured Tailwind wrong. I followed a different video on how to install Tailwind and I pasted the above image slide on hover code to that environment and now it works !

Comment: And apart from this hover effect not working, is the rest of tailwind working as expected in your local environment? Are all the other tailwind stylings applied correctly? To find out if anything is wrong in your local environment, you could recreate your tailwind play in codesandbox.io and see if it works there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Kokodoko Apart from the hover effect, the width of the images do not match the width in the video. Rest of Tailwind is working as usual and the stylings are applied correctly. I will try recreating it in codesandbox.io.